# Help with MySQLdb module: corrupted installation and connecting to remote servers

Tags: python, mysql, python-module, mysql-python, setup.py

I am new to Python and having some rudimentary problems getting MySQLdb up and running.  I'm hoping somebody out there can help me.

When I first tried to install the module using setup.py, the setup terminated because it was unable to find mysql_config.  This is because I didn't realize the module expected MySQL to be installed on the local machine.  I am only trying to connect to a remote MySQL server.

My question is twofold:

1) How should I use MySQLdb on a machine that doesn't have MySQL installed, only to connect to a remote server?

2) How can I roll back what appears to be a corrupt installation of MySQLdb?  Whenever I try to import MySQLdb from a script, I get the error "no module named _mysql", which according to the documentation, indicates a faulty install.

BTW: I am on a Mac running Snow Leopard/Python 2.6.1

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the full traceback???

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the MySQL client libraries.
2. Install the MySQL client library development files, and build again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is this the correct lib? [http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads)

Comment: Looks right to me. And it has both the runtime and development files.